# SQL Server 2005 how to write view or sp for this example

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this

```
cod        KM            RT
174        202,203       45
202        174           35
94         202,174       25
203        null          null
```

I want to write view and view one column like this:

```
cod        KM            RT         RTKM
174        202,203       45         35      --(sum RT 202 and RT 203)
202        174           35         45      --(RT 174)
94         202,174       25         45+35   --(sum RT 202 and RT 174)
203        null          null       null
```

Comment: To start with you would need a view that separates the values in the KM field into separate fields.  You can then write a query with joins on those fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.cod
    ,a.KM
    ,a.RT
    ,SUM(b.RT) RTKM
FROM yourTable a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourTable b ON 
        a.KM IS NOT NULL
            AND (
                a.KM = b.cod -- single value
                OR a.KM LIKE b.cod + ',%' -- first value of the list
                OR a.KM LIKE '%,' + b.cod + ',%' -- value in the middle of the list
                OR a.KM LIKE '%,' + b.cod) -- last value of the list
GROUP BY a.cod
    ,a.KM
    ,a.RT
```

Comment: tnx but i want to only view, no another table